# Stop YouTube video from playing when div is closed

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, show-hide

How do I stop the YouTube video from playing when the div is closed?

Demo: http://defroster.99k.org/layers.php

THANKS

Comment: you can watch the first vid with the second quite well :D what happens if you try setting/removing the iframes src dynamically

Comment: suggestion : https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference

Comment: Thx, It's a little over my knowledge. Any ideas how to easily change the code to apply this. Or does anyone know a site that has a tutorial? Thx a million

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to use the js_api_reference...

You'll need to clear the div object by doing

```
$('#slidingDiv').html('');  or rebuild the html
```

after the sliding is finished, and then rebuild the html content again when you activate that.

try this
http://jsfiddle.net/fedmich/GTedm/

```
$('#slidingDiv').slideToggle('', function (){
    var obj = $(this);
    if(obj.is(':hidden')){
        obj.html( obj.html() );
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! But I am so confused where to enter this code. Shall I add it to the http://defroster.99k.org/incl/showHide.js

Comment: How do I use your code to have several items on a same page? I really appreciate your help

Comment: Hmm, the script you have now dont support callback, so we need to add that in first.
Question, are you fixed and decided to use that script already or maybe you are planning to use other script still?
What you're trying to do are called Accordion, maybe you could check some simple accordion available on the net first.
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion

Comment: I would be happy to use the great code you supplied!! It works great! But how do I use it with several items on the same page (about 5 videos)? Like on this page: 

http://defroster.99k.org/layers.php Thanks again!

Comment: @Marcus Silverman: try customizing the jquery selector to point to each diffrent item.. $('#slidingDiv1'), $('#slidingDiv2') etc.